# How to customize a progressbar in android

Tags: android, customization, android-progressbar

How to create a customized indeterminate progress bar in android?
I described it below to show you how you can use a customized progress bar in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a customized ProgressBar in android I've used this method

1- create an image file (custom_blue.png) which is replace with default indeterminate ProgressBar [image]

2- create a xml file into drawable with this code(my_progress_indeterminate.xml):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/custom_blue"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" />
```

3- insert a ProgressBar into your layout

```xml
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/custom_progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:indeterminateBehavior="repeat"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/my_progress_indeterminate"
    android:maxHeight="24dp"
    android:maxWidth="24dp"
    android:minHeight="24dp"
    android:minWidth="24dp" />
```

4- that's all. now use this ProgressBar as before in your java Activity